# Maven: unable to install 3rd party jar

Tags: maven-2

trying to install a 3rd party jar into my repository (alfresco-repository.jar). I'm using the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=alfresco -DartifactId=alfresco -Dversion=3.1 -Dpackaging=jar "-Dfile=C:/Users/xxx/Development/WIP/Alfresco/common/jars/alfresco/3.1/lib/alfresco-repository-3.1.jar" -DgeneratePom=true -e
```

and I'm getting the following exception (-e used for more information):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'install'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Invalid task '.1': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in
 the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Invalid task '.1': you must specify a va
lid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:plugin
ArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor
(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1830)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListBy
AggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
0)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Comment: You sure you didn't enter 'mvn .1 xxxxxxxxx' by mistake? I get this exact output if I do...

Comment: Pretty sure. I copied the line above straight from my powershell window.

Comment: Strange. Did you try to use `"-Dversion=3.1"`?

Comment: romaintaz, that was it. please post it as an answer and I'll vote it up and give it the answer...

Comment: @Bryce - The solution romaintaz suggested will not necessarily work the same on all platforms. My answer gives the correct solution to your problem which will work on all platforms. Accept?

Comment: THanks @Jesse. Seems like that was a Looong time ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using double quotes (") in the wrong places and sometimes not at all. You should be using double quotes around all of your values of parameters. For instance...

```
"-Dfile=C:/Users/xxx/Development/WIP/Alfresco/common/jars/alfresco/3.1/lib/alfresco-repository-3.1.jar"
```

...should be...

```
-Dfile="C:/Users/xxx/Development/WIP/Alfresco/common/jars/alfresco/3.1/lib/alfresco-repository-3.1.jar"
```

...and...

```
-Dversion=3.1
```

...should be...

```
-Dversion="3.1"
```

Different command lines of different OS's will handle the first versions inconsistently but if you surround only the *value* of each parameters with double quotes, you will get the desired behavior every time. Your entire command should look like this...

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId="alfresco" -DartifactId="alfresco" -Dversion="3.1" -Dpackaging="jar" -Dfile="C:/Users/xxx/Development/WIP/Alfresco/common/jars/alfresco/3.1/lib/alfresco-repository-3.1.jar" -DgeneratePom="true" -e
```

I'll admit it is not necessary on all of them but it is a good habit to have.

Comment: Now worked in my scenario. Please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449991/maven-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-omnesys-omne-om-omn/62450552?noredirect=1#comment110450773_62450552